# How to display 3 static columns and rest dynamic columns in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am facing a strange issue while displaying a grid in Angular which has 3 static columns and the next columns can be anything dynamic .

For eg - My data from Backend looks like -

```
{
    "CONNECTOR": "D00425B",
    "PIN": "A03",
    "DESCRIPTION": "DME Source",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA305": "1",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA504": "0"
  },
  {
    "CONNECTOR": "D00425B",
    "PIN": "B03",
    "DESCRIPTION": "G/S Source",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA305": "0",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA504": "1"
  },
```

And i want my Angular grid to look like

```
Connector      Pin        Description     Effectivity-VA305       Effectivity-VA504

D00425B        A03        DME Source              1                    0

D00425B        B03        G/S Source              0                    1
```

The first three columns ( Connector , Pin , Description ) will always be there , But the other 2 columns can vary , it can be 2 , 3 , 4 or n number of columns .

For eg if my data comes as -

```
{
    "CONNECTOR": "D00425B",
    "PIN": "A03",
    "DESCRIPTION": "DME Source",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA305": "1",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA504": "0"
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA385": "1",
  },
  {
    "CONNECTOR": "D00425B",
    "PIN": "B03",
    "DESCRIPTION": "G/S Source",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA305": "0",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA504": "1",
    "EFFECTIVITY - VA385": "1",
  },
```

Then my grid should change as -

```
Connector      Pin        Description     Effectivity-VA305   Effectivity-VA504    EFFECTIVITY -VA385

D00425B        A03         DME Source              1                      0               1


D00425B        B03         G/S Source              0                      1               1
```

I am currently taking the data source for the MatTable like -

```
<mat-table id="hexCodeMatTable" class="paddingTable" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': innerWidth }" [dataSource]="gridDataSource" matSort style="overflow: auto;">
```

and the columns name as -

```
<mat-header-row class="headerHeight" *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay" ></mat-header-row>
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>
```

Not able to achieve dynamic column names , Please help

Comment: if you change the variable `columnsToDisplay` the mat-table not change? -it's the only you need-

Comment: @Eliseo - But the columnsToDisplay value will change as per user's input , that will be dynamic . That's my query , how to achieve that

Comment: How do you want the user can change the columnsDisplay? I put an answer using checkBoxs but I don't know about your requirements

Answer (score 0):

it's only a variable. How you want change?

If is using a series of checkBox you can has some like

```
<input type="checkBox" [ngModel]="displayedColumns.indexOf('name')>=0"
   (ngModelChange)="change($event,'name')">Name
</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkBox" [ngModel]="displayedColumns.indexOf('weight')>=0"
   (ngModelChange)="change($event,'weight')">Weight
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkBox" [ngModel]="displayedColumns.indexOf('symbol')>=0"
   (ngModelChange)="change($event,'symbol')">Symbol
</label>
```

In .ts you has

```
sortedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol']; //<--a duplicate of your displayColumns
change(value:boolean,column:string)
  {
    if (value && this.displayedColumns.indexOf(column)<0)
    {
        this.displayedColumns.push(column);
        this.displayedColumns.sort((a,b)=>this.sortedColumns.indexOf(a)>this.sortedColumns.indexOf(b)?1:-1)
    }
    if (!value && this.displayedColumns.indexOf(column)>=0)
          this.displayedColumns=this.displayedColumns.filter(x=>x!=column)
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ub1bdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

A brief explain. I use [ngModel] && (ngModelChange). Yes, you can use [ngModel]="some different a variable". So I needn't declare a extra variable. In this case is checked if displayedColumns (an array) has one element with "name" for the first case, "weigth" for the second and "symbol" for the last one.

I use the same function in ngModelChange. See that $event is true or false if che check box is selected or not. But I pass an addicional argument, the name of the column we can hide/show.

Comment: No , this is not my query . I think you understood it wrong . Anyways thank you

Comment: Well, I think that I know yet what do you want. As the table is the same for all the data, you must create the table with all the possible columns. Then, when you received the data (in the subscribe), change the variable "this.columnsToDisplay" according the data you received, I think that you can simple write:`this.columnsToDisplay=Object.keys(result[0])`